# Creating user in Docker Oracle

Tags: oracle, docker

I have a .dmp file with full database, so I created a new oracle container in docker from this image:https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:4:793825823433:::4:P4_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_EULA_ID,P4_BUSINESS_AREA_ID:803,803,Oracle%20Database%20Express%20Edition,Oracle%20Database%20Express%20Edition,1,0&cs=377bZCP_xqhY-I3nvTrMVnqg_FNF40Y8HGfThKfEBufE2HadWDFDEQKFRN9iSIVG75S9DMpJL0gyOYFGHA3_P6g

Then, I have copied .dmp file to my contaner's storage:
`docker cp C:\Users\a.skripnikov\Downloads\isuzht.orw_scheme_dev_tk2_2023-06-01-18-16_dp.tar\isuzht.orw_scheme_dev_tk2.dmp ITK2:/opt/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/isuzht.orw_scheme_dev_tk2.dmp`

After that I tried running this command:
`impdp system/itk2@ORCLCDB.localdomain dumpfile=isuzht.orw_scheme_dev_tk2.dmp logfile=itk2_log_file.log`

But got an error:

```
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"DEV_TK2"."VIVSD_ASTN_GETSTATIONFACT" failed to create with error:
ORA-01918: user 'DEV_TK2' does not exist
```

So I tried creating user 'DEV_TK2' like this:

```
GRANT CREATE USER TO sys;
CREATE USER DEV_TK2 IDENTIFIED BY DEV_TK2;
```

But got an error:
`SQL Error [65096] [99999]: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name`

I tried running this before creating user, but it didn't help:
`GRANT CREATE USER TO sys;`

I was also able to create common user C##DEV_TK2, but it doesn't solve the error while restoring my dump.